# Actor or actress that have won best actor Oscar for role in sci-fi film

Tags: movie, awards

Are there any actors or actresses that have won an Academy award for best actor or supporting actor for their role in a sci-fi film?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use a fairly inclusive definition of "sci-fi" for a couple of these but...

Fredric March won Best Actor in 1932 for [Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Jekyll_and_Mr._Hyde_%281931_film%29).
Cliff Robertson won Best Actor in 1968 for [Charly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charly).
Don Ameche won Best Supporting Actor in 1985 for [Cocoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoon_%28film%29).
Heath Ledger won Best Supporting Actor in 2008 for [The Dark Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_%28film%29).